# Python One-Shot, level-trigger, edge-trigger

Tags: python, twisted

I am monitoring a boolean value in a python-twisted framework.  When the boolean value changes I want to execute a function only once.  Can this be done in Python?

I am pulling the boolean value in from an IO device serially.  The value is polled on some time interval. When the value changes I want to execute a function.

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a function that executes exactly one time? Or how to monitor the value of some boolean variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better to do it with a class than with globals.

```
class EdgeTrigger(object):
    def __init__(self, callback):
        self.value = None
        self.callback = callback

    def __call__(self, value):
        if value != self.value:
            self.callback(self.value, value)
        self.value = value
```

To use this code, create an object with the function that should be called:

```
def my_callback(oldVal, newVal):
    print "Value changed from {0} to {1}.".format(oldVal, newVal)

detector = EdgeTrigger(my_callback)
```

Then "call" the object with each new value as you get it:

```
with open("infile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        detector(line.strip())
```

This will read lines from a file and print a message when two consecutive lines are not the same.

```
$ cat infile.txt 
1
1
1
2
2
1

1
2
2
5
$ python edgedetect.py
Value changed from None to 1.
Value changed from 1 to 2.
Value changed from 2 to 1.
Value changed from 1 to .
Value changed from  to 1.
Value changed from 1 to 2.
Value changed from 2 to 5.
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Implemented your code and it works beautifully.  Detects a digital input signal change just like what I was needing.

Comment: +1 - Here we are 5 years later and with some slight modding I was able to use this class to monitor a flag Digital input that triggered data collection from an Analog input. This EdgeTrigger class helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edge triggering just requires remembering the previous value.

```
_prev_value = False
def check_value(val):
    global _prev_value
    change = None
    if val and not _prev_value:
        change = 'up'
    elif _prev_value and not val:
        change = 'down'
    _prev_value = val
    return change
```

And, obviously, this could be implemented in a class instead of using a global.